# MVC 3 Ajax.BeginForm submit issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-ajax, unobtrusive-ajax

im trying to submit a form by pressing a button that eventually will refresh the table

this is the form :

```
@{
AjaxOptions ajaxOpts = new AjaxOptions
{
    Confirm = "start ???",
    UpdateTargetId = "MainTable",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    Url = Url.Action("Refresh","MainScreen"),
    LoadingElementId = "loading",
    LoadingElementDuration = 2000,



};}
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(ajaxOpts)){

<div id="loading" style="display: none; color: Red; font-weight: bold">
    <p>
        Loading Data...</p>
</div>

<div id="header">

    <input type="button" value="Submit Form" />

</div>
<table id="MainTable">
    <tr>
        <th>
            ServiceId
        </th>
        <th>
            ServiceInstanceId
        </th>
        <th>
            MessageRole
        </th>
        <th>
            Datetime
        </th>
        <th>
            Message
        </th>
        <th>
            Status
        </th>
        <th>
            ESBErrorCode
        </th>
        <th>
            ESBTecnicalErrorCode
        </th>
        <th>
            ErrorDescription
        </th>
        <th>
            PortName
        </th>
        <th>
            MachineName
        </th>
        <th>
            ConsumerId
        </th>
        <th>
            ExternalId
        </th>
        <th>
            ConsumerMachineName
        </th>
        <th>
            ServiceBehavior
        </th>
        <th>
            RouterConsumerId
        </th>
        <th>
        </th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ServiceId)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ServiceInstanceId)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MessageRole)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Datetime)
            </td>
            <td>
                \
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Message.Context)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ESBErrorCode)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ESBTecnicalErrorCode)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ErrorDescription)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PortName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MachineName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ConsumerId)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ExternalId)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ConsumerMachineName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ServiceBehavior)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RouterConsumerId)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
}
```

this is the Controler :

> public ViewResult Refresh()
>           {

```
        var tracks = db.Tracks.Include(t => t.Message);
        return View(tracks.ToList());
    }
```

for some reason when i submit the button nothing happen

i already added

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

thanks 
miki

Comment: Check with a breakpoint in your `Refresh` method that your action is being called. Can you see the request in your browser development console? (in Chrome, IE you can access it with F12 look for the network tab in FF you can use firebug)

Comment: the break point didn't catch anything  or the network tab :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unobtrusive js helper listens on the submit event with

```
$("form[data-ajax=true]").live("submit"...
```

but your "submit" button is "just a button" not a submit button:

```
<input type="button" value="Submit Form" />
```

Change it to `type="submit"`and it should work:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit Form" />
```

Comment: Change it to type="submit"and it should work:

<input type="submit" value="Submit Form" />

that fix it thanks :) :) :)